# Substract a value from a cell if value is less than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to have in my Excel sheet a column of numerical values and if a particular cell has value less than 0, then substract this negative value from value of another cell. Example:

D5 contains value 300.

D6 contains value 5 -- nothing to substract from D5.

D7 contains value -1 -- now substract: D5-D7 (or actualy D5+(-D7), result of D5: 299).

D8 contains value 0 -- nothing to substract.

D9 contains value -100 -- now substract: D5-D7-D9 (result of D5: 300-1-100 = 199).

And so on, and so on...

How can I achive that?

Comment: Do you want the result in its own cell or do you want to replace an existing value ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent the goal is to update D5 value only. So based on my example, when I add D10 cell with value -99, D5 would have value 100 (300-1-100-99 = 100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **change** a value requires a nacro.  If we start with:

[image]

First select cell **D5** and run this short macro:

```
Sub DecreaseValue()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, M As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    M = ActiveCell.Column

    For i = ActiveCell.Row + 1 To N
        If Cells(i, M).Value < 0 Then
            ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + Cells(i, M).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will produce:

[image]

You can avoid using a macro by using a separate cell to hold the decreased value.  For example, in cell **E5** enter:

```
=D5+SUMPRODUCT((D6:D9999<0)*(D6:D9999))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The second solution (with additional cell) is exactly what I need.

Comment: @mchfrnc  Thank you for the feedback.